# Date is not written in desired format in CSV

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have an array list which looks like below:

```
data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

data.add(new String[] {"Date","Day_Of_Week"});

data.add(new String[] {"2011-1-10","xyz"});

data.add(new String[] {"2011-1-11","xyz"});

data.add(new String[] {"2011-1-12","xyz"});
```

Then, I write the data from the above ArrayList to a CSV file using following code:

```
String csv = "D:\\Output.csv";
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

writer.writeAll(data);

writer.close();
csvReader.close();
```

If I open my `Output.csv` file, the format of the date is:

```
1/10/2011

1/11/2011

1/12/2011
```

Can anybody help why this is happening? Does CSV file automatically change the format of the date when writing it int the file?

Comment: did you open it in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open file in another program. For example notepad.
Excel can show you reformat view.